# Using Generic TList with Interfaces in C++Builder

Tags: generics, c++builder

How can I create a list of interface instances in C++Builder? I am trying the following, but the compiler complains from each of these in different ways:

```
#include <System.Generics.Collections.hpp>
...
TList__1<IInterface> IntfList;
TList__1<_di_IInterface> IntfList;
TList__1<DelphiInterface<IInterface>> IntfList;
```

on the other hand, I cannot generate the list with objects either.

```
TList__1<TObject> ObjList = new TList__1<TObject>();
```

so I am quite lost, it seems, and the doc doesn't help either

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList

Or is there an alternative way that would work better? Eventually, I will need an array, but I want to build it dynamically using `Add`, and then get it from `IntfList->ToArray()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `TList<T>` is a Delphi `TObject`-derived class, so it *must* be created dynamically via `new` in C++, eg:

```cpp
TList__1<T> *MyList = new TList__1<T>;
...
delete MyList;
```

Where `T` can be `_di_IInterface`, `TObject*` (note the `*`), etc.

Now, that being said...

> How can I create a list of interface instances in C++Builder?

In short, you can't do that with `TList<T>` in pure C++ code by itself. This is documented behavior:

[How to Handle Delphi Generics in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Generics_in_C%2B%2B)

> Delphi generics are exposed to C++ as templates. However, it is important to realize that the instantiations occur on the Delphi side, not in C++. Therefore, **you can only use these template for types that were explicitly instantiated in Delphi code**.
>
> ...
>
> **If C++ code attempts to use a Delphi generic for types that were not instantiated in Delphi, you'll get errors at link time**.

There are no default instantiations of `TList<IInterface>` in the native RTL or VCL/FMX frameworks.  So you would have to add your own Delphi code to your C++Builder project to create such instantiation, eg:

MyTListInstantiationUnit.pas

```pascal
unit MyTListInstantiationUnit;

interface

{$HPPEMIT '#pragma link "MyTListInstantiationUnit"'} 

// or in XE5 Update 2 and later:
// {$HPPEMIT LINKUNIT}

implementation

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

initialization
  TList<IInterface>.Create.Free;
finalization

end.
```

MyCppUnit.cpp

```cpp
#include <System.Generics.Collections.hpp>
#include "MyTListInstantiationUnit.hpp"
...
TList__1<_di_IInterface> *IntfList = new TList__1<_di_IInterface>; // should work now
```

Otherwise, you can use [`TInterfaceList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TInterfaceList) instead:

```cpp
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
...
TInterfaceList *IntfList = new TInterfaceList;
...
delete IntfList;
```

Or, if you don't really need to pass an interface list across the C++/Delphi boundary, then consider using a pure-C++ container like `std::vector` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<_di_IInterface> IntfList;
```

As for `TList<TObject>`, it actually does exist in the native Delphi RTL, but it is not working for you simply because you are not using it correctly. It needs to look more like this instead:

```cpp
TList__1<TObject*> *ObjList = new TList__1<TObject*>;
...
delete ObjList;
```

Otherwise, you can use [`TObjectList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <System.Contnrs.hpp>
...
TObjectList *ObjList = new TObjectList;
...
delete ObjList;
```

Or, just use `std::vector<TObject*>` instead.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, I am really struggling with C++ examples for our Delphi library and all sorts of issues like this come ahead, where I have no clue. This explains it, and I wish the documentation for TList<T> would have been pointing to that article, too. - So my Delphi class expects an DynamicArray<IMyInterface> - if I read you right, there is no neat way to construct that except by starting with the array upfront?

Comment: @JouniAro you don't need TList to work with DynamicArray. They are completely separate things. But yes, if you need to pass in a DynamicArray, then you will have to construct and fill it as needed, eg: `DynamicArray<_di_IMyInterface> arr; arr.Length = ...; /* fill arr ... */ MyComponent->DoSomething(arr);`

Comment: yes I know of course that. TList is just more convenient to fill without defining the length upfront. That's why I had been using it in the Delphi example, which I am trying to replicate. But I will do without. Tx for clearing this up.

Comment: @JouniAro "*TList is just more convenient to fill without defining the length upfront*" - unless you need to interact with Delphi code, I would just use `std::vector` for that.

Comment: Yeah, this is example code that interacts with Delphi components, so it expects a DynamicArray. Are there any easy means available to convert the std-types to Delphi(?) types, for example std::vector to DynamicArray? I guess DynamicArray is a Delphi type, isn't it?

Comment: @JouniAro `DynamicArray` is a C++ wrapper for a Delphi array type, yes. And you will have to copy the data manually from one container to another, eg: `std::vector<T> vec; ... DynamicArray<T> arr; arr.Length = vec.size(); std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr.begin()); ...`

Comment: Tx again; confirms my assumption. Good to know the std::copy function for future reference, but I will try to keep the C++ examples as close to the Delphi ones as possible in this case.

Comment: @JouniAro "*Good to know the std::copy function for future reference*" - also see [C++ Iterator Support for Delphi Enumerable Types and Containers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Iterator_Support_for_Delphi_Enumerable_Types_and_Containers)

Comment: Tx, looks very useful.